# Changing the value of a session with Ajax in Wordpress not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I´m kind of new to using Ajax but I am trying to update the value of a session using Ajax. The Ajax call shoud fires when clicked on a button.

When I click on this button it also returns the succes function. I am using Wordpress with this Ajax call.

Currently this is my code:

Ajax call:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
                data: {click: "true"},
                success: function() { 
                    alert('bro it worked!'); 
                }
            }); 
});
```

functions.php in Wordpress: session_start();

```
function notificationCall() { 
  $_SESSION['clicked'] = $_POST['click']; 
  die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_notificationCall', 'notificationCall');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_notificationCall', 'notificationCall');

echo $_SESSION['clicked'];
```

So my Ajax call returns the succes function containing a string with "Bro it worked". However, my session always stays my same default value of "false".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason it's always true is because your ajax post data `data: {click: "true"}` is hardcoded to true, and since that's what you're setting the value of it with `$_SESSION['clicked'] = $_POST['click'];`, then it will always be true.

one solution might be to hard code a toggle in there:

```
function notificationCall() {
  if ($_SESSION['clicked'])
     $_SESSION['clicked'] = false;
  else
     $_SESSION['clicked'] = true;
  die(); 
}
```

**update**

I think you'll need to specify the php function to call inside your ajax request data, so that should look something like this:

```
data: {action: "notificationCall", click: "true"},
```

Comment: Woops my mistake there Jeff. I made a little typo. My default value is 'false' and not 'true'.

Comment: you could just toggle the state everytime the `notificationCall` function is called. I've updated my answer with a possible solution

Comment: This does not use the Ajax right? The session value should only be changed to 'true' when clicked on a button. And the default value always has to be 'false'.

Comment: ah, I think you're missing the function call inside your ajax request data `action: "notificationCall"`

Comment: Hi Jeff, your last comment seems do have done the trick! I had to specify the action inside of `data`. Thanks very much for the help!